# Posting to Two tables from One Form MySQLi with foriegn key

Tags: php, mysqli

So, I have one form and I'm trying to insert data (via POST) to two tables. 
There is a foreign key linking both tables by `AUTO_INCREMENT ID`.

I've searched the site extensively and tried all the suggested (for those issues) and none worked.

I'd assume this is because their problem was similar, but not exact to mine.

**Here's my PHP**:

```
// Escape user inputs for security
$companyName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['companyName']);
$companyAddress =mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['companyAddress']);
$companyCity = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['companyCity']);
$companyState = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['companyState']);
$companyZip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['companyZip']);
$companyPhone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['companyPhone']);
$companyURL = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['companyURL']);
$contactName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['contactName']);
$contactEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['contactEmail']);
$contactPosition = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['contactPosition']);

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO companyData (companyName, companyAddress, companyCity, companyState, companyZip, companyPhone, companyURL) 
VALUES ('$companyName', '$companyAddress', '$companyCity', '$companyState', '$companyZip', '$companyPhone', '$companyURL')";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO contactData (contactName, contactEmail, contactPhone, contactPosition) 
VALUES ('$contactName', '$contactEmail', '$contactPhone', '$contactPosition')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "<center><h1>Record updated successfully.<br>
Go <a href='data/form_companyinfo.php'>Here </a>Next</h1></center>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us the error message or described exactly your database schema, but here's a guess:

Use `mysqli_insert_id()` after the first insert so that you can supply the resulting id (returned by `mysqli_insert_id()`) to the following INSERT statement.

Comment: Wow.... that was quick. Thanks for the reply.

"Error: Out of range value for column 'companyID' at row 1"

Comment: companyData
      companyID (AI)
      companyName
      companyAddress
      companyCity
      companyState
      companyZip
      companyPhone
      companyURL
contactData
     contactID (AI)
     contactName
     contactEmail
     contactPhone

 Foreign key constraint (INNODB)
       'database'.'companyData'.'companyID'
        constraint name: contact_id_fk_idx
       on DELTE cascade
       on UPDATE no action

Comment: Have a look at the data type of companyID and the value you are trying to insert. It looks as though it may mean just what it says. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html